# (gulp-jsvalidate) implementation for syntax error detection?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a js folder that i want to process using gulp. However, when there is a syntax error the output of gulp trace doesn't specify the file with the error.

Right now my gulpfile looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var esnext = require('gulp-esnext');
var es6ModuleTranspiler = require("gulp-es6-module-transpiler");
var bower = require('gulp-bower');
var jsValidate = require('gulp-jsvalidate');

var paths = {
  scripts: ['js/**/*.js'],
  js: 'public/js'
}

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  gulp
    .src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(esnext())
    .pipe(es6ModuleTranspiler({
      type: "amd",
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js));
});

gulp.task('validate', function () {
  gulp
    .src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(jsValidate());
});

ulp.task('bower', function() {
  bower()
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts, ['scripts']);
});

// The default task (called when you run `gulp` from cli)
gulp.task('default', ['validate', 'bower', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

As you can see I wrote the *validate* task to pipe gulp-jsvalidate through the scripts.path. The goal was to detect syntax errors and find out which files those errors where.

However, when I run gulp it throws an error the following trace:

```
Error: gulp-jsvalidate: Line 1: Unexpected identifier
```

I don't mind switching to other plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect syntax errors I use [gulp-jshint](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-jshint) The default reporter print the file and corresponding line numbers. If you like more stylish reporter then you can use [jshint-stylish](https://github.com/sindresorhus/jshint-stylish).

Comment: Thank you! Didnt know these plugins!

Answer (score 1):

You can add gulp-debug (written by the same author) before in the pipeline to display the name of the file currently being processed : https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-debug

```
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
gulp.task('validate', function () {
  gulp
    .src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(jsValidate());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jsValidate returns error, which you can catch and use its members to gather more information.

```
gulp.task('validate', function () {
   gulp
      .src(paths.scripts)
      .pipe(jsValidate())
      .on('error', onError);
});

function onError(error) {
   gutil.log(error.message);

   if (error.plugin === 'gulp-jsvalidate') {
       gutil.log('In file: ' + error.fileName);
   }

   process.exit(1);
}
```